# Circuit element: Rectangle with diagonal

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am a newbie in electronics, so please bear with me.
I have a Induction proximity sensor which I have to integrate with a data logger. But, I have run into an issue with a circuit element. I am unable to understand the circuit element which is represented as a rectangle with a diagonal. Also, what is the quantification parameter of the same? Please help me out with the same.

Thank you

[image: Circuit diagram as provided]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the symbol for a relay coil. The relay should be a DC type with a coil voltage equal to the DC power supply.

24 V DC is common in industrial control systems and, since your switch is rated for 300 mA max., the minimum coil resistance can be calculated from \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {24}{0.300} = 80 \ \Omega \$.

The switch is NPN type which means that there is an NPN transistor internally that will connect the black and blue wires internally when the switch is 'on'. This may also be called a 'switched negative'. The relay '+' terminal is always connected to the positive supply.